# Why this is written using past form?

Tags: grammar, aspect

This is the text:

> ああ 僕 まだ 名乗ってませんね｡
>   あした お会いしたときに｡

It is referring to tomorrow, so I would naturally say: お会いするときに instead.

Why does he use a past form?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

There is not any past form, this is the *accomplished* form.

"あした お会いしたときに" could be translated as: "once I met him/her tomorrow".
So, even it this takes place in the future, the person is speaking about when the action of meeting the other person is accomplished.
Whereas お会いするときに is the time where the person *is about to* meet (this is not done yet) the other person.

Comment: This is also called the "perfective aspect". It just means that the action is completed. So, お会いした doesn't mean that the action referred to happened in the past. It just means that it's completed. Or in the case of your example, "when we meet" or "once we've met".

Comment: @sazarando "Perfective" is technically incorrect and you should say "perfect", which the rest of your comment correctly explains.